# jQuery, Binding to HTML Buttons

Tags: jquery, xml, events, binding, event-handling

I have been working on a new project, a demo of which can be [viewed here](http://apostic.com/galsmall/gallery.html).
Most of the things are ready to go as they are but my main issues come with a jQuery portfolio plugin I am using. You can view the demonstration of its usage [here](http://pexeto.com/tonic_gallery/).
You can see that on the demo page under the head **Default Settings, 12 items per page** that it is using a custom header to filter between categories defined on an XML generated page, code to which is as under;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portfolio>

<categories>
    <category id="cardgames">Card Games</category>
    <category id="environments">Environments</category>
    <category id="character">Character</category>
    <category id="animations">Animations</category>
</categories>
<!-- Items Start -->
<items>
<!-- Individual Item Starts -->
    <item>
        <thumbnail>images/thumbnails/1-thumb.jpg</thumbnail>
        <preview>images/jpegs/1.jpg</preview>
        <category>cardgames,environments,character,animations</category>
        <description>Description goes here</description>
    </item>
<!-- Individual Item Ends -->
<!-- Individual Item Starts -->
    <item>
        <thumbnail>images/thumbnails/2-thumb.jpg</thumbnail>
        <preview>images/jpegs/2.jpg</preview>
        <category>cardgames,environments,character,animations</category>
        <description>Description goes here</description>
    </item>
<!-- Individual Item Ends -->
<!-- Individual Item Starts -->
    <item>
        <thumbnail>images/thumbnails/3-thumb.jpg</thumbnail>
        <preview>images/jpegs/3.jpg</preview>
        <category>cardgames,environments,character,animations</category>
        <description>Description goes here</description>
    </item>
<!-- Individual Item Ends -->
<!-- Individual Item Starts -->
    <item>
        <thumbnail>images/thumbnails/4-thumb.jpg</thumbnail>
        <preview>images/jpegs/4.jpg</preview>
        <category>cardgames,environments,character,animations</category>
        <description>Description goes here</description>
    </item>
<!-- Individual Item Ends -->
<!-- Individual Item Starts -->
    <item>
        <thumbnail>images/thumbnails/5-thumb.jpg</thumbnail>
        <preview>images/jpegs/5.jpg</preview>
        <category>cardgames,environments,character,animations</category>
        <description>Description goes here</description>
    </item>
<!-- Individual Item Ends -->
</items>
</portfolio>
```

You can see that the categories for the filters are being defined here on XML and then being called through a second JavaScript, code to which is;

```
(function($){
$.fn.portfolioSetter=function(options){
    var defaults={
        //default settings
        itemsPerPage: 10, //the number of items per page
        pageWidth: 840,  //the width of each page
        pageHeight:320,  //the height of each page
        itemMargin:15,  //margin of each of the portfolio items
        showCategories: false,  // if set to false, the categories will be hidden
        allText: 'ALL', //the ALL text displayed before the categories names
        easing: 'easeOutExpo', //the animation easing
        animationSpeed: 800, //the speed of the animation of the pagination
        navButtonWidth:30,  //the width of the pagination button 
        wavyAnimation:false, //if set the true, all the elements will fade in consecutively with a wavy effect
        xmlSource : 'portfolio.xml',  //the XML file from which the data is exctracted
        pageWrapperClass: 'page_wrapper',  //the class of the div that wraps the items in order to set a page
        navigationId: 'portfolio_pagination',  //the ID of the pagination div
        categoriesId: 'portfolio_categories', //the ID of the categories div
        itemClass: 'portfolio_item' //the class of the div that wraps each portfolio item data
    };

    var options=$.extend(defaults, options);
    options.pageHolder=$(this);

    //define some helper variables
    var categories=[], items=[], pageWrappers=[], imagesLoaded=0, counter=0, ie=false, categoryHolder;

    var root=$('<div />').css({width:(options.pageWidth*2), height:options.pageHeight, float:'left'});
    $(this).css({width:options.pageWidth, height:'auto', overflow:'hidden'}).append(root);
    var parentId=$(this).attr('id');


init();
function init() {
    root.parent().append('<div class="loading"></div>');
    loadItems();
}

/**
 * Parses the XML portfolio item data.
 */
function loadItems(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: options.xmlSource,
        dataType:'xml',
        success:function(xml){

            //get the settings
            if($(xml).find('show_categories:first').text()==='off'){
                options.showCategories=false;
            }               

            if(options.showCategories){
                //get the portfolio categories
                $(xml).find('categories').eq(0).find('category').each(function(i){
                    var current=$(this);
                    var category = {
                        id: current.attr('id'),
                        name: current.text()
                    };
                    categories.push(category);
                });
            }

            //get the portfolio items
            $(xml).find('item').each(function(i){
                var current=$(this);
                var thum=current.find('thumbnail:first').text();
                var prev = current.find('preview:first').text();
                var cat=current.find('category:first').text().split(',');
                var desc = current.find('description:first').text();

                var item = {
                    thumbnail:thum,
                    preview:prev,
                    category:cat,
                    description:desc,
                    obj:$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'"><a rel="lightbox_'+parentId+'" class="single_image" href="'+prev+'" title="'+desc+'"><img src="'+thum+'" /></a></div>')
                };
                items.push(item);
            });

            setSetter();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Calls the main functions for setting the portfolio items.
 */
function setSetter(){

    if($.browser.msie){
        ie=true;
    }
    root.siblings('.loading').remove();
    root.after('<div id="'+options.navigationId+'"><ul></ul></div>');
    if(options.showCategories){
        displayCategories();
    }
    loadImages();

}

/**
 * Displays the categories.
 */
function displayCategories(){

    categoryHolder=$('<div id="'+options.categoriesId+'"></div>');  
    categoryHolder.append('<div id="portfolio_categories_left"></div><ul></ul><div id="portfolio_categories_right"></div>');
    root.before(categoryHolder);
    var catUl=categoryHolder.find('ul#links');


    //add the ALL link
    var allLink= $('<li>'+options.allText+'</li>');
    catUl.append(allLink);
    showSelectedCat(allLink);

    //bind the click event
    allLink.bind({
        'click': function(){
            displayItems();
            showSelectedCat($(this));
        },
        'mouseover':function(){
            $(this).css({cursor:'pointer'});
        }
    });

    //add all the category names to the list
    var catNumber=categories.length;
    for(var i =0; i<catNumber; i++)(function(i){
        var category = $('<li>'+categories[i].name+'</li>');
        catUl.append(category);

        //bind the click event
        category.bind({
            'click': function(){
                displayItems(categories[i].id);
                showSelectedCat($(this));
            },
            'mouseover':function(){
                $(this).css({cursor:'pointer'});
            }
        });
    })(i);
}

function showSelectedCat(selected){
    //hide the previous selected element
    var prevSelected=categoryHolder.find('ul li.selected');
    if(prevSelected[0]){
        var prevHtml=prevSelected.find('div.port_cat').html();
        prevSelected.html(prevHtml);
        prevSelected.removeClass('selected');
    }

    //show the new selected element
    var html = selected.html();
    selected.html('<div class="port_cat_active"><div class="port_cat_l"></div><div class="port_cat">'+html+'</div><div class="port_cat_r"></div> </div>');
    selected.addClass('selected');
}

/**
 * Loads the images. When all the images are loaded calls the displayItems 
 * function to display the images.
 */
function loadImages(){
    var imageCount=items.length;
    for(var i in items){
        if(items.hasOwnProperty(i)){
         var img = new Image();
            $(img).load(function() {
                imagesLoaded++;
                if(imagesLoaded===imageCount){
                    //all the images are loaded, display them all
                    displayItems();
                }
            }).attr('src', items[i].thumbnail);  
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the portfolio items.
 */
function displayItems(){

    var filterCat=arguments.length===0?false:true;

    //reset the divs and arrays

    root.html('');
    root.width(200);
    pageWrappers=[];
    root.animate({marginLeft:0});

    var length=items.length;    

    counter=0;
    var catId=arguments[0];
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        (function(i, filterCat, catId) {

            if(!filterCat || (filterCat && items[i].category.contains(catId))){
                if(counter%options.itemsPerPage===0){
                    //create a new page wrapper and make the holder wider
                    root.width(root.width()+options.pageWidth+20);
                    var wrapper=$('<div class="'+options.pageWrapperClass+'"></div>').css({float:'left', width:options.pageWidth+options.itemMargin, height:options.pageHeight});
                    pageWrappers.push(wrapper);
                    root.append(wrapper);
                }

                if(ie){
                    //var obj=$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'" style="background-image:url('+items[i].thumbnail+');" ><a rel="lightbox" class="single_image" href="'+items[i].preview+'" title="'+items[i].description+'"></a><img class="hidden" /></div>');
                    var obj=$('<div class="'+options.itemClass+'" ><a rel="lightbox_'+parentId+'" class="single_image" href="'+items[i].preview+'" title="'+items[i].description+'"><img src="'+items[i].thumbnail+'" /></a></div>');
                    pageWrappers[pageWrappers.length-1].append(obj.css({display:'none'}));
                    items[i].obj=obj;
                }else{
                    pageWrappers[pageWrappers.length-1].append(items[i].obj.css({display:'none'}));
                }

                var timeout=counter>=options.itemsPerPage?0:100;

                if(counter>=options.itemsPerPage || !options.wavyAnimation){
                    items[i].obj.fadeIn().animate({opacity:1},0);
                }else{
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        //display the image by fading in
                        items[i].obj.fadeIn().animate({opacity:1},0);
                    },counter*100);
                }

                counter++;
            }
    })(i,filterCat, catId);

    //call the lightbox plugin
    $('a[rel="lightbox_'+parentId+'"]').colorbox({current:"{current}/{total}"});

    //show the navigation buttons
    showNavigation();
    setHoverFunctionality();

}


/**
 * Displays the navigation buttons.
 */
function showNavigation(){
    //reset the divs and arrays
    var navUl=root.siblings('#'+options.navigationId).find('ul');
    navUl.html('');

    var pageNumber=pageWrappers.length;
    if(pageNumber>1){
        for(var i=0; i<pageNumber; i++)(function(i){
            var li = $('<li></li>');
            navUl.append(li);
            //bind the click handler
            li.bind({
                'click': function(){
                    var marginLeft=i*options.pageWidth+i*options.itemMargin-2;

                    //set a bigger margin for IE6
                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7) {
                        marginLeft+=i*options.itemMargin;
                    }
                    root.animate({marginLeft:[-marginLeft,options.easing]}, options.animationSpeed);

                    navUl.find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                },
                'mouseover':function(){
                    $(this).css({cursor:'pointer'});
                }
            });
        })(i);

        navUl.find('li:first').addClass('selected');

        //center the navigation
        var marginLeft=(options.pageWidth)/2-pageNumber*options.navButtonWidth/2;
        navUl.css({marginLeft:marginLeft});
    }
}

function setHoverFunctionality(){
    $('.portfolio_item').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.8}, 300);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 300);
    });
}
};
```

So besides all  the customizations being offered in the aforementioned javascript code which I have already achieved, the function that sets the category click event handlers is **displayCategories()** starting on line 117 of the file.
What this function does is creating the category elements from the ones that are set in the XML file, it appends the category <li> elements to a parent <ul> element and sets the click handlers to them.

Have a look at my website's gallery again, here on left sidebar you can see HTML buttons under 'All Art Work'

These are 5 buttons in total created through CSS sprites, I am trying to use them instead of the custom XML header to filter between categories!
What I tried is to leave the left sidebar empty and leave the gallery code create the links automatically.
I created an empty <ul> tag in the left sidebar and assigned the selector of that tag on line 122 of JS file:

**var catUl=categoryHolder.find('ul');**

So that the code can append the category links to that ul and I can test if this will work et all. I met a dead-end here.

**My question** in short is, is there another, simpler way through which I can call the categories through my HTML anchored buttons from the javascript file or any events I can create as to meet this requirement?

You might have already figured out I am not a JS guru so your help is much welcomed.
Thanks & Regards.
PS: Pls ask away any code from the XML or JavaScript files, I'll repost for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much you can do there without drastically modifying the plugin. The plugin is doing all the XML parsing for you, and both the category names and their click events, while they could be inserted/attached in much less aggravating ways, pull values from their respective XML nodes. Everything *I* would change would involve re-parsing the XML, so the effort seems to be much greater than the payoff.

Comment: Damn, I have been already doing lots of the 'greater effort' already  :( and spent some hard earned money on that plugin too. Well, I understand that XML re-parsing would be a real hectic job. So anyway out of this? Or anyone knows an identical plugin that I can use for my project?

Comment: Well, bearing in mind that I don't know what the full scope of your project is, the XML for the category navigation doesn't seem to be offering you anything you couldn't just as easily obtain with a bit of actual HTML and javascript. Have you thought about just putting buttons into the HTML and creating your own click events? Create the click events inside the plugin and they can simply call displayItems('categoryname'))

Comment: Thanks for the response Pete, that's exactly what im gonna do now. Will post the update page soon. Just sad about the money I wasted on the worthless plugin SMH.

Comment: Heya guys, finally after 2 days of hardcore effort I've got my own filterable jquery working, basically a mix of Quciksand/Pretty Photo and a custom pagination script I got gowing; [**have a look!**](http://apostic.com/new/gallery.html)